# Implementation of a Lateral contoller using non linear model predictive control in GEKKO

Tags: gekko, mpc, lateral

I am trying to implement a lateral controller for an autonomous vehicle defined by a lateral dynamic model.Well, my problem is that the CVs don't reach the desired reference or target point set by SP. I am using the following equations of motion and objective function. I am using a semi empirical formula (pacejka) to calculate tire forces donated by Fyf Fyr. Here are the [equations of motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcAIH.png) and [objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol7Ka.png). Thanks in advance.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 
import math


#%% NMPC model
T = 5
nt = 51
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,T,nt)

#Model Parameters
X_speed = m.Param(value=10.0)
mass=m.Param(value=1611.0)
c=m.Param(value=1.351) 
b=m.Param(value=1.5242)
Iz=m.Param(value=3048.1) 

Cyf=m.Param(value=1.30)
Dyf=m.Param(value=3449.94238709)
Byf=m.Param(value=0.223771457713)
Eyf=m.Param(value=-0.6077272729)

Cyr=m.Param(value=1.30)
Dyr=m.Param(value=3846.47835351)
Byr=m.Param(value=0.207969093485)
Eyr=m.Param(value=-0.7755647971)

#Variables
slip_angle_front_tire = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-10.0, ub=14.0 )
slip_angle_rear_tire = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-10.0, ub=14.0 )

phi_f = m.Var(value=0.0)
phi_r = m.Var(value=0.0)

maxF = 5000

Ffy = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-.0*maxF, ub=maxF )
Fry = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-1.0*maxF, ub=maxF )

 
xpos = m.Var(value=0.0)
dy = m.Var(value=0.0)
dpsi = m.Var(value=0.0)

#MV
steering = m.MV(value=0, lb=-0.40, ub=0.40 )

#CV
ypos = m.CV(value=0.0 ,lb =-200.0,ub=200.0 )
psipos = m.CV(value=0.0,lb=-3.5,ub=3.5)

#Equations
m.Equation(ypos.dt() == dy)
m.Equation(psipos.dt() == dpsi)

m.Equation(slip_angle_front_tire == steering - m.atan( (dy+b*dpsi)/X_speed ) )
m.Equation(slip_angle_rear_tire == -1.0*m.atan( (dy-c*dpsi) / X_speed))

m.Equation(phi_f == (1-Eyf)*(slip_angle_front_tire) + (Eyf/Byf)*(m.atan(Byf*slip_angle_front_tire) ) )
m.Equation(phi_r == (1-Eyr)*(slip_angle_rear_tire) + (Eyr/Byr)*(m.atan(Byr*slip_angle_rear_tire) ) )

m.Equation(Ffy == (Dyf*( m.sin(Cyf*m.atan(Byf*phi_f ) ) ) ) *2.0 )
m.Equation(Fry == (Dyr*( m.sin(Cyr*m.atan(Byr*phi_r ) ) ) ) *2.0 )

m.Equation(mass*dy.dt() == (Ffy*m.cos(steering) ) + (Fry) - (X_speed*dpsi*mass) ) 
m.Equation(dpsi.dt()*Iz == ( b*Ffy*m.cos(steering) ) - ( c*Fry) )

#Global options
m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2
m.options.MV_TYPE = 0

#MV tuning
steering.STATUS = 1
steering.DCOST = 0.01

#CV Tuning
ypos.STATUS = 1
psipos.STATUS = 1

ypos.TR_INIT = 2
psipos.TR_INIT = 2


ypos.WSP = 100 
psipos.WSP = 10

ypos.SP = 9.2
psipos.SP = 1.5

print('Solver starts ...')
t = time.time()
m.solve(disp=True)
print('Solver took ', time.time() - t, 'seconds')

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,steering.value,'b-',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('steering wheel')

plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,ypos.value,'r--',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('y-point')

plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,psipos.value,'r--',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('yaw angle')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reference trajectory, you need to include the time constant `TAU` for *how fast to reach the setpoint*.

```py
ypos.TAU = 1.5
psipos.TAU = 1.5
```

There is additional information on [tuning an MPC application in the Dynamic Optimization exercises](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning).

One other correction that you need is the `-1.0` in `Ffy = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-1.0*maxF, ub=maxF)`. Otherwise, it can never reach the setpoint. It appears that both setpoints cannot be reached so it preferentially tries to meet the `ypos` setpoint that has a higher weight. You may need another `MV` to control both `ypos` and `psipos`. Otherwise, you may consider opening the `steering` bounds to see if it can find a better solution with fewer restrictions. I also set the end time to 10 with 101 points because it needed additional time to stabilize to the new setpoint.

[image: optimal control]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time 
import math


#%% NMPC model
T = 10
nt = 101
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,T,nt)

#Model Parameters
X_speed = m.Param(value=10.0)
mass=m.Param(value=1611.0)
c=m.Param(value=1.351) 
b=m.Param(value=1.5242)
Iz=m.Param(value=3048.1) 

Cyf=m.Param(value=1.30)
Dyf=m.Param(value=3449.94238709)
Byf=m.Param(value=0.223771457713)
Eyf=m.Param(value=-0.6077272729)

Cyr=m.Param(value=1.30)
Dyr=m.Param(value=3846.47835351)
Byr=m.Param(value=0.207969093485)
Eyr=m.Param(value=-0.7755647971)

#Variables
slip_angle_front_tire = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-10.0, ub=14.0 )
slip_angle_rear_tire = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-10.0, ub=14.0 )

phi_f = m.Var(value=0.0)
phi_r = m.Var(value=0.0)

maxF = 5000

Ffy = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-1.0*maxF, ub=maxF )
Fry = m.Var(value=0.0, lb=-1.0*maxF, ub=maxF )


xpos = m.Var(value=0.0)
dy = m.Var(value=0.0)
dpsi = m.Var(value=0.0)

#MV
steering = m.MV(value=0, lb=-0.4, ub=0.4 )

#CV
ypos = m.CV(value=0.0 ,lb =-200.0,ub=200.0 )
psipos = m.CV(value=0.0,lb=-3.5,ub=3.5)

#Equations
m.Equation(ypos.dt() == dy)
m.Equation(psipos.dt() == dpsi)

m.Equation(slip_angle_front_tire == steering - m.atan( (dy+b*dpsi)/X_speed ) )
m.Equation(slip_angle_rear_tire == -1.0*m.atan( (dy-c*dpsi) / X_speed))

m.Equation(phi_f == (1-Eyf)*(slip_angle_front_tire) + (Eyf/Byf)*(m.atan(Byf*slip_angle_front_tire) ) )
m.Equation(phi_r == (1-Eyr)*(slip_angle_rear_tire) + (Eyr/Byr)*(m.atan(Byr*slip_angle_rear_tire) ) )

m.Equation(Ffy == (Dyf*( m.sin(Cyf*m.atan(Byf*phi_f ) ) ) ) *2.0 )
m.Equation(Fry == (Dyr*( m.sin(Cyr*m.atan(Byr*phi_r ) ) ) ) *2.0 )

m.Equation(mass*dy.dt() == (Ffy*m.cos(steering) ) + (Fry) - (X_speed*dpsi*mass) ) 
m.Equation(dpsi.dt()*Iz == ( b*Ffy*m.cos(steering) ) - ( c*Fry) )

#Global options
m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1

#MV tuning
steering.STATUS = 1
steering.DCOST = 0.1

#CV Tuning
ypos.STATUS = 1
psipos.STATUS = 1

ypos.TR_INIT = 2
psipos.TR_INIT = 2

ypos.WSP = 100 
psipos.WSP = 10

ypos.SP = 9.2
psipos.SP = 1.5

ypos.TAU = 1.5
psipos.TAU = 1.5

print('Solver starts ...')
t = time.time()
m.solve(disp=True)
print('Solver took ', time.time() - t, 'seconds')

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,steering.value,'b-',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('steering wheel')

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot([0,10],[9.2,9.2],'k-')
plt.plot(m.time,ypos.value,'r--',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('y-point')

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot([0,10],[1.5,1.5],'k-')
plt.plot(m.time,psipos.value,'g:',LineWidth=2)
plt.ylabel('yaw angle')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped me . I modified the model and added 2 more equations until I reached my target points for ypos and psi . I obtain the steering (MV) in nearly 0.9 seconds is there a way to obtain it faster ? like in range of 0.1 to 0.5 secs ? I tried tuning the mpc but it did not make difference.It is just very critical as this controller will be applied on a real car where I need a frequency range between 2 to 10 Hz. Thanks in advance .

Comment: To speed up the application, you could do a couple things: (1) Use `m.time = [0,0.2,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.6,2.0,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6]` or something similar instead of uniformly spaced intervals. Only the first step `[0,0.2...]` needs to be equal to your controller cycle time, (2) Compile the Python script. The solver time is only a fraction of the total time as shown with print(m.options.SOLVETIME), (3) Don't print the output by setting `disp=False`, (4) Test repeat solves to see if an initialized solution improves the performance. There are other methods as well.

Comment: If you can't get it run fast enough or your online architecture doesn't support a computationally-intensive operation then I'd recommend that you look at explicit-MPC or other fast MPC options such as In Situ Adaptive Tabulation. https://apm.byu.edu/prism/index.php/Projects/InSituAdaptiveTabulation  These methods rely on storage and retrieve of approximate solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your care ! I really appreciate it . I also had another question , why gekko does not find a solution for many setpoints ? maybe because of the complexity of the model ?

Comment: If I transformed the system to 1st order would this differ ?

Comment: If you have one MV then you can typically reach one CV set point. If you have two CVs then you'll typically need two MVs to reach both. Here is an example of multivariate control: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/AdvancedTemperatureControl

Comment: yes I got it as it is an under actuated system . I obtain the value of steering (mv) by steering.value[0] is this the first step in control sequence that should be applied to the system ? (control input)

Comment: You can use `steering.NEWVAL` that is equal to steering.value[1]. You want to use the second point, not the first. The first is just the initial condition.